# mysql - row timestamp by hour of day

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have a table as below:

| tmstp in | tmstp out | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-30 14:10:00 | 2021-01-30 15:50:00 | 01:40:00 |
| 2021-01-30 15:55:00 | 2021-01-30 16:05:00 | 00:10:00 |
| 2021-01-30 19:00:00 | 2021-01-30 22:10:00 | 03:10:00 |

but I was wondering in a table like this:

| tmstp in | tmstp out | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-30 14:10:00 | 2021-01-30 14:59:59 | 00:49:59 |
| 2021-01-30 15:00:00 | 2021-01-30 15:50:00 | 00:50:00 |
| 2021-01-30 15:55:00 | 2021-01-30 15:59:59 | 00:04:59 |
| 2021-01-30 16:00:00 | 2021-01-30 16:05:00 | 00:05:00 |
| 2021-01-30 19:00:00 | 2021-01-30 19:59:59 | 00:59:59 |
| 2021-01-30 20:00:00 | 2021-01-30 20:59:59 | 00:59:59 |
| 2021-01-30 21:00:00 | 2021-01-30 21:59:59 | 00:59:59 |
| 2021-01-30 22:00:00 | 2021-01-30 22:10:00 | 00:10:00 |

this will be the expexted output that each row is inside a hour. the interval of row must be inside a hour

thanks for any help

Comment: what do you want to do with `tmstp out`? Do you want o update it? or do you want to ignore it? (or something else....)

Comment: what database are you using (I do see Gordon deleted [sql-server])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend aligning the times on the hour, rather than one second before the hour.

With this change, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select ts_in, date(ts_in) + interval hour(ts_in) + 1 hour as ts_hour_end, ts_out
      from t
      union all
      select ts_hour_end, date(ts_hour_end) + interval hour(ts_hour_end) + 1 hour, ts_out
      from cte
      where ts_hour_end < ts_out
     )
select ts_in, least(ts_hour_end, ts_out), timediff(least(ts_hour_end, ts_out), ts_in) as diff
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6eee7a6d6a1c3cc12bcba2149e7f2c08) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Tks @Gordon Linoff to your answer!worked perfectly. it´s possible to write this code on PL / SQL way?

Comment: @TiagoOliveira . . . This basically works in Oracle 12+, but you need to include the columns for the CTE rather than the `recursive` keyword, and adjust the date arithmetic.